# C# MVC seeding DB not working - NullErrorException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, dbcontext

I am using ASP.NET Identity and I have created two tables inside the database to extend the functionality of it. One table mantains a many-to-many relation with AspNetRoles and the other one is the result of that relation. (I don't think that this is important, but just in case)

Inside IdentityConfig.cs I have the following code:

```
public class ApplicationDbInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        IList<ExtendedIdentity> extendedIdentityList = new List<ExtendedIdentity>
        {
            new ExtendedIdentity() { Name = "TestName1" },
            new ExtendedIdentity() { Name = "TestName2" }
        };

        foreach (var item in extendedIdentityList)
        {
            context.Extension.Add(item); //THE ERROR SHOWS UP HERE
        }

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Inside IndentityModels.cs I have the following code:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole()
    {
    }

    public ApplicationRole(string name)
        : base(name)
    {
    }

    //

    public virtual ICollection<ExtendedIdentity> Extension{ get; private set; }
}

public class ExtendedIdentity
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; private set; }

}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        :base("LocalTestingDB", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }

    public DbSet<ExtendedIdentity> Extension;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ExtendedIdentity>()
            .ToTable("Extension")
            .HasKey(x => x.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>()
            .HasMany<UserPermission>(ar => ar.Extension)
            .WithMany(ei => ei.Roles)
            .Map(arei =>
                {
                    arei.MapLeftKey("RoleId");
                    arei.MapRightKey("ExtensionId");
                    arei.ToTable("AspNetRoleExtension");
                });
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Where it says "THE ERROR SHOWS UP HERE" in the code is where I get the Null Error Exception. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I need to seed the Roles and Extension tables when the DB is created. If someone can help me I would really appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `context.Extension` is `null` and your code is trying to call the `Add` method on `null` which is causing the typical Null reference exception.

The reason is it null is because you did not define it as a property which is settable & gettable. A property without a `set` accessor is considered read-only. A property without a `get` accessor is considered write-only. In your case you made your property neither readable nor writable!

In your `ApplicationDbContext` class, update the property definition to have `set` and `get` accessors and it should work

```
public DbSet<ExtendedIdentity> Extension; { get;  set; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Just a detail, do you think that is ok the code written in that way? Because I red in a couple of places that I should dispose the context but not sure if here is necesary

Comment: for that, you can use `using(var db=new ApplicationDbContext()) { // use db now// }`